# Activation function for performing counting, modified version of leaky ReLU

Tags: activation-function, relu

Is there any known activation function that is like a leaky ReLU but also has its growth capped at the top once it reaches one through linear growth? I mean something like this.

[image: Example of my activation function at value x]

I need this for performing a comparison (checking if one element is smaller than the other, `1` if true, `0` if not), but I don't want the gradients to vanish when `y >>> x`, as is the case with sigmoid and other similar activation functions. That's why I was thinking of using this described variant of leaky ReLU with a very small alpha.